# group by and count values from text field

Tags: mysql

my table looks like:

```
ID, TEXT_FIELD
--
1  "Text, me RR"
2  "Another, me AA"
3  "New, me CC"
4  "Like, me RR"
```

I would like to group and count all "me RR", "me AA", "me CC" and in the best case I would like to finally get:

```
RR 2
AA 1
CC 1
```

Any idea please how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and **[RIGHT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_right.asp)** to do it

```
SELECT right(t.TEXT_FIELD,2),count(t.id) 
   FROM yourtable t GROUP BY t.TEXT_FIELD
```

Comment: I think you need to alias the `RIGHT` in the result set and `GROUP BY` this alias.

Comment: correct, alias is needed to get nice clean results. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select text_of_interest , count(text_of_interest)
from your_table
group by substring(text_field, length(text_field) - 2, 3) as text_of_interest
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the right most string on text column and group by alias

mysql> select * from test1;

+----+----------------+

| ID | TEXT_FIELD     |

+----+----------------+

|  1 | Text, me RR    |

|  2 | Another, me AA |

|  3 | New, me CC     |

|  4 | Like, me RR    |

+----+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select right(TEXT_FIELD, 5) as col,count(ID) from test1 group by col;

+-------+-----------+

| col   | count(ID) |

+-------+-----------+

| me AA |         1 |

| me CC |         1 |

| me RR |         2 |

+-------+-----------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)